# Injector Error while trying to configure angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Currently my index.html has the following setup. The javascript file (js/app.js) is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngRoute']);

app.controller('RootCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
});

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
  $scope.pageName = 'Home';
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  }).when('/location/:locId', {
    templateUrl: 'location.html',
    controller: 'LocationCtrl'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

The HTML File:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Firebase App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Firebase Libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "___",
      authDomain: "___.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://___.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "___.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "___"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

  <!-- AngularFire -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.1.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="RootCtrl">
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Running this gives the following error:

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A336)(…)
```

Not sure of what is going wrong. Additionally did some debug to notice that this failure is caused when trying to inject `firebase` module.

Comment: I don't see an AngularFire `script` in there.

Comment: @cartant Do you mean there is some issue with the way `app.js` has been set up? AngularFire has been imported right before `js/app.js`

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Apparently, I don't know how to work a scroll bar. How embarrassing.

Comment: `$firebaseObject` is a service provided by angularfire. Although you are calling angularfire in a script tag just before `app.js`, you have not injected it into your app module (i.e. `var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngRoute', 'angularfire']);` However, with your setup, this may not be necessary (my setup is somewhat different from yours), so assuming it is not necessary, I strongly suspect that angularfire itself has injected dependencies that are not loading or are not loading in time. I am still debugging a similar problem and will post an answer once I find it out myself.

Comment: @samurai_jane tried that as well, still the same result.

Comment: @Sneha Lohar, I have been running into this exact same issue although my setup is different than yours. I hope to have a solution soon to share with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment in another answer and your script:

The problem is with your app.js script. When you minify your script, your variables will get renamed, in this case, `$routeProvider` will become somthing like `e` and angular will no longer be able to inject. Change your config call to:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  }).when('/location/:locId', {
    templateUrl: 'location.html',
    controller: 'LocationCtrl'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);
```

Also, make similar changes to your controller. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

After taking your code and building your app on my machine locally, my best guess is `ng-app="app"` cannot see your `app.js` file. When you declare `ng-app`, Angular looks for the module called whatever you name it (in this case, "app"). If it can't find it, you get the error you are getting (which, admittedly, is very vague).

Either your server is not setup correctly to find `app.js` or the path you have declared is incorrect. One way to test this is to put `app.js` in the same folder as `index.html` and then replace

`<script src="js/app.js"></script>`

with

`<script src="./app.js"></script>`

Would love to hear what ultimately solves your issue.

Comment: Tried this but no result. Currently was using minified (closure compiled) version of the above script. Changing that to un-compiled version along with removing all additional firebase script (firebase-*) gets this to run. Not sure what's causing the issue when compiled.

Comment: Just saw the answer by @vivekprakash. Totally forgot about that but that's the right answer.